# Ordered list of C# properties, for common operations?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, properties, model

Background: I have a form ViewModel with 7 properties, each ViewModel representing sections of a wizard, and all implement IFormSection. I'm trying to use a single definition (i.e. DRY/SPoT) for these ViewModels between multi-section AJAX clients and single-section JavaScript-disabled clients.

It's important to have these accessible as properties so the automated serialization/deserialization works (i.e. ASP.NET MVC model binding), and those properties must also be individually nullable to indicate unsubmitted sections.

**But I also have 6-10 occasions to iterate through these serializable properties with common IFormSection operations, in some cases in an ordered fashion. So how can I store this list of properties for reuse?** EDIT: This includes batch `new()`ing them up in a full load operation.

For example, maybe the end result looks something like:

```
interface IFormSection {
    void Load();
    void Save();
    bool Validate();
    IFormSection GetNextSection(); // It's ok if this has to be done via ISectionManager
    string DisplayName; // e.g. "Contact Information"
    string AssociatedViewModelName; // e.g. "ContactInformation"
}
interface ISectionManager {
    void LoadAllSections(); // EDIT: added this to clarify a desired use.
    IFormSection GetRequestedSection(string name); // Users can navigate to a specific section
    List<IFormSection> GetSections(bool? ValidityFilter = null);
    // I'd use the above List to get the first invalid section
    // (since a new user cannot proceed past an invalid section),
    // also to get a list of sections to call .Save on,
    // also to .Load and render all sections.
}
interface IFormTopLevel {
    // Bindable properties
    IFormSection ProfileContactInformation { get; set; }
    IFormSection Page2 { get; set; }
    IFormSection Page3 { get; set; }
    IFormSection Page4 { get; set; }
    IFormSection Page5 { get; set; }
    IFormSection Page6 { get; set; }
    IFormSection Page7 { get; set; }
}
```

I'm running into problems where I can't have abstract static methods, resulting in too many reflection calls or generics to do stupid stuff, and other problems that just make my whole thought process smell bad.

Help?

p.s. 
I accept I may be overlooking a much simpler design involving delegates or something. I also realize I have SoC issues here, not all of which are a result of summarizing the problem for StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm currently trying to have each property merely reflect a single member of an OrderedDictionary, but I'm having trouble envisioning how it will work.

Comment: You may want to simply save each step in the wizard separately instead of chaining the properties like this. I'm speaking from experience when I say its just so much easier to debug and work with that way.

Comment: @jfar: Would you please clarify "save"? You mean the http post operation? Or do you mean create switch statements in the controller for each CRU(D) reponsibility? I don't want separate URLs for each form step, because I want to be able to rationally open the first invalid page (after tightening data validation rules, for example).

Comment: Yes, save each form in the wizard separately.  Same URL?  Jeeze, you are really making things hard for yourself for no reason.  Its really simple to detect one part of the process isn't filled out and then redirect to that particular page in the wizard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order is constant, you can have a property or method returning `IEnumerable<object>`; then yield return each property value... or `IEnumerable<Tuple<string,object>>`... which you can iterate over later.

Something super simple like:

```
private IEnumerable<Tuple<string,object>> GetProps1()
{
   yield return Tuple.Create("Property1", Property1);
   yield return Tuple.Create("Property2", Property2);
   yield return Tuple.Create("Property3", Property3);
}
```

if you wanted a more generic approach doing the same thing, you can use reflection:

```
private IEnumerable<Tuple<string,object>> GetProps2(){
   var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties();
   return properties.Select(p=>Tuple.Create(p.Name, p.GetValue(this, null)));
}
```

or, idk? an extension method maybe?

```
private static IEnumerable<Tuple<string,object>> GetProps3(this object obj){
   var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
   return properties.Select(p=>Tuple.Create(p.Name, p.GetValue(obj, null)));
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jon. Yes, the order will be constant. Ok, so this doesn't allow me to batch `new()` them up followed by `.Load()` since I can't set values here, but that's probably acceptable (and I see I didn't really state that scenario in my question).  I could do that separately via reflection.